# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when I saving png to MemoryStream in IIS7

Tags: .net, iis-7, bitmap, png, memorystream

I have an error when I try save png to memory stream. On my ASP.NET Development Server everything works but when I run site under IIS7 - there are generated an error. Also when I try saving jpg format - everything right too. In IIS I have setting .NET Trusted Level to Full. But it still doesn`t work. I need your help.

```
private static Stream DrawBarChart(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, ulong, double>> data){
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var canvasWidth = PageSize.A4.Width;
    var canvasHeight = PageSize.A4.Height;

    using (
        System.Drawing.Image bitmap = new Bitmap((int) canvasWidth,
                                                 (int) canvasHeight))
    {
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            var penBlack1 = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);

            graphics.DrawLine(penBlack1, 0, 0, canvasWidth, 0);
            graphics.DrawLine(penBlack1, 0, 0, 0, canvasHeight);

            graphics.Save();
        }
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

    stream.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    return stream;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could it have something to do with GDI+ (which Graphics is merely an encapsulation for) not being supported on services? [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx): _"GDI+ functions and classes are not supported for use within a Windows service. Attempting to use these functions and classes from a Windows service may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions or errors."_

Comment: What is an alternative way to generate picture can be used?

Comment: Graphics.Save does not what you think it does. Google it.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 completely independent problems in your code that cause its malfunctioning.

## Problem #1: The GDI+ error

This is a recurring issue that keeps on springing all over the place in the ecosystem.
I had it, I managed to fix it, now I can't remember exactly how.
I tried to replicate your problem and I failed in receiving a failure.

I suggest you check this thread: http://forums.asp.net/t/624305.aspx/1
Here some guys have happily managed to overcome the problem by:

- Making sure they disposed all of their Bitmap instances before carrying on with other drawings
- (**interesting one**): Doing a **GC.Collect()** (probably after each bitmap rendering)

This is not the main reason why I wanted to try and help you with an answer.
It seems that you already did (you say you did) all the things I usually do to make sure I don't end up in this situation (security, trust, etc). Furthemore, you clean up after yourself more than needed (a bit too much as you will find out while reading my answer).

I find that your code has a second problem about which you are probably unaware.
By simply solving that problem in my own VS environment, I successfully rendered Bitmaps (both in IIS 7 and in Express and in the ASP Development Server).

It is highly possible that by reorganizing things a bit in you application's code, you will manage to solve Problem #1. So: please check out what I have to say about Problem #2.

## Problem #2: Streams cannot be disposed and returned at the same time

You can't go and return streams that you just created **and disposed** like:

```
public static Stream SomeMethod() {
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    // write something to the stream
    return stream;
  }
}
```

I really don't understand how that piece of code actually works in ASP.NET Development Server.
The issue I'm trying to point out here is that your code would always throw an ObjectDisposedException (regardless of whether you're running the code as a service or in interactive user space):

[image: Cannot access a closed stream]

Who closese the stream ? The termination of the **using** statement.

## Possible solutions to problem #2

A quick solution to this particular problem (that could use up more memory than you predicted) would be to make your method return a byte[] instead of a stream.

```
public static byte[] SomeMethod() {
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {

    // ... create bitmap and render things ...

    // write something to the stream
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

    return stream.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Allowing my self to make assumptions about your applications needs I would say that this other solution might be even better:

**If** it is the case that you wish to return these generated chart images to *< img >* tags back to the Web Browser, and you're accomplishing this by means of, say, ASP.NET Generic Handlers, then you could pass the OutputStream of the current WebResponse **to** your drawing method, instead of taking a resulting byte[] (or Stream) **from** it, like so:

In HTML:

```
<img src="path/Foo.ashx" alt="chart" ... etc ... />
```

while up in the app:

```
public class Foo : IHttpHandler {
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {

   context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
   Stream alreadyExistingStream = context.Response.OutputStream;

   Etc.SomeMethod(stream);       
  }
}

public class Etc {

public static void SomeMethod(Stream stream) {
  // There used to be a using here that would create a stream
    // simply because the parameter name **stream** is the same as the former local var's name
    // the instructions that do the drawing of things 
    // + saving of the resulting Bitmap **to** the stream
    // keep on compiling without any problems

    // draw things to a bitmap
    // write the bitmap to the stream
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

    // returning stuff is not needed anymore
  // This used to be the time and place where the stream would be disposed
  // and it's resources given back to the community
}

}
```